# How to list Streams owned by a Project Area using Jazz RTC Java API

Tags: java, groovy, rational-team-concert

I am working an automation for IBM Rational Team Concert (IBM aka Jazz RTC).

How may one list all streams owned by a specific project area?
Which are the required API calls?

I could not find any getters in the IProjectArea instance, nor service or client instances with such methods. And I could not figure out how to use search criteria for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The streams owned by a project area may be queried using `IWorkspaceSearchCriteria`. Because streams are, actually, workspaces of type 'stream'. The API is not quite clear how to specify the owning project area.

1. Get the `IWorkspaceManager` from the `ITeamRepository`, which contains the `findWorkspaces` method.
2. You don't need `IProjectAreaHandle`. Only the project area name.
3. Create a `IWorkspaceSearchCriteria` and set `kind` to `IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS` and set `exactOwnerName` to the string containing the project area name.
4. Call `IWorkspaceManager.findWorkspaces(...)` to get a list of `IWorkspaceHandles`. The first parameter is the search criteria. Se second parameter is the maximum number of results (which I set to `IWorkspaceManager.MAX_QUERY_SIZE`, which is 512. The third parameter is the progress monitor, which may be `null`.
5. If you need to get stream name, description or other attributes, then you need to call `IItemManager.fetchCompleteItems(...)` fetch the full `IWorkspace` instances.

Here is an example in Groovy:

```groovy
Lit<IComponentHandle> listComponents(String projectAreaName) {
  final manager = repositoty.getClientLibrary(IWorkspaceManager) as IWorkspaceManager;
  final criteria = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
  criteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS);
  criteria.setExactOwnerName(projectAreaName)
  final itemManager = repositoty.itemManager()
  return itemManager.fetchCompleteItems(handles, IItemManager.DEFAULT, null) as List<IWorkspace>
}
```